# Subtracting numbers that are in the string

Tags: python, coordinates, subtraction, pyautogui

I've got 2 coordinates(x,y) and I want to subtract them from each other

You can ignore that it is in pyautogui, just how can I subtract test1-test2

```
import pyautogui

test1 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("test1.png",confidence=0.8)

test2 = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("test2.png",confidence=0.9)

print(test1)

print(test2)

>>>Point(x=1072, y=543)

>>>Point(x=1304, y=689)
```

Comment: something like `test1[0] - test2[0]` would get You x I assume

Comment: Hello @Michal, welcome. In the future, please format your post better. See how to insert syntax highlighting for code here https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

[The `pyautogui` documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#screenshot-functions) suggests that `test1` and `test2` values are Python tuples, not `Point` objects:

> The `locateCenterOnScreen()` function just returns the XY coordinates of the middle of where the image is found on the screen:
>
> ```
> >>> pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('looksLikeThis.png')  # returns center x and y
> (898, 423)
> ```

To [access elements of a tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp), you can use `[0]`, `[1]`, and so on, to get the first, second, and subsequent elements.

To take the difference of two tuples, you can [use `map`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) to run an [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp) on each pair of elements from `test1` and `test2`:

```
diff = tuple(map(lambda i, j: i - j, test1, test2))
```

Note that the order of tuples will change the result. The result of `test1 - test2` will be different from `test2 - test1`. So you might instead want the [absolute value](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_abs.asp) of the difference:

```
abs_diff = tuple(map(lambda i, j: abs(i - j), test1, test2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can cast the Point object to a list

```
test1 = list(test1)
```

and then access to X or Y coordinate with:

```
print(f"X coordinate: {test1.x}")
print(f"Y coordinate: {test1.y}")
```

Comment: It's not working because x and y is not defined, but thank you for answer.